# Alert me emails

Tags: alert

when sending an alert it comes up like this:

****Alert 'Punch List: Control room A/C intake and exhaust grills' has successfully been added on '19676 AB Inbev'. 
You will receive alerts according to the delivery method, timing and criteria that were selected when the alert was created.
You can change this alert or any of your other alerts on the My Alerts on this Site page.****

**But we need more info on the main email. One time it came through like this:**

```
Duct heater has been added
```

Austin Nelson
11/4/2016 12:22 PM
Title:  Duct heater

Assigned To:    Eddie Verrett

Issue Status:   Active

Priority:   (2) Normal

Description:    Verify igniter rod and how it operates in the Duct Heater.  Re-tighten crush collar holding igniter rod.

Category:   (2) Category2

Due Date:   11/7/2016 12:00 AM

Related Issues:

Comments:   Igniter operation has been verified. Just need to tighten crush collar.

Date Completed:

We need to know how to get all the information sent with the alert.